# Store objects of three different classes in an array

Tags: c++

This is an interview question:
how can we store the objects of let's say 3 different classes which are totally independent of each other.

**My answer was:**
create an array which stores all void pointers.
like :

```
void *array[];
```

and store the pointers of all the objects.the array elements can be many.
but for retrieving the elements,i said we can use the dynamic cast or the static cast!
this i think is the wrong answer.i think `dynamic cast` and `static cast` are supposed to be used among the classes which are dependent.
please correct me if i am wrong.

if dynamic cast and static cast doesn't work.May be we can use `reinterpret cast`.

but is this the correct way to do this task?

Comment: @Rahul Dravid You need a Tuple.

Comment: If you'd have to do this, you should use a safe solution like `boost::any`.

Comment: @Red Hue: (1) why (??) and (2) how

Comment: he was not interested in boost.

Comment: @Angel: No, C does not have UDTs defined with the keyword `class`. C does have user-defined types in general, though (see: `struct`) and thus this question would be applicable to both languages... if it weren't for the `{dynamic,static,reinterpret}_cast` references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you trying to make this so complicated?

```
struct T {
   T1 obj1;
   T2 obj2;
   T3 obj3;
};
```

If you instead mean that you have an array of objects, and each element can be of any of three distinct, unrelated types, then it's a silly interview question because it's a silly thing to do.

(Yes, you would consider `reinterpret_cast` if forced to employ this approach by limited job opportunities and a pressing need to consume food.)

Comment: if it was silly - why were `boost::any` or `boost::variant` created?

Comment: If you'd go the non-boost way, at least make it a discriminated union? I know there are (severe) restrictions to what types can be used as union members, _but_ many of these restrictions are lifted with the advent of c++0x

Comment: @Nim: So people can hack around stupid designs. Are you going to claim that the mere existence of a thing means that the requirements that leads to its use therefore _must_ be non-silly?

Comment: @Nim: cut the guy some slack? Without a context defining why this (supposed optimization) is needed, it _is_ silly. It's called a-propos. Context might make it less silly, and instantly into boost material
.

Comment: I cannot accept this answer even though you are right in mentioning about this structure.I actually had this as the first thing on my mind.But he said he specifically wants an array itself and he does not want a structure.he specifically wants an array which should hold the pointers of all kinds of classes intended.

Comment: @Rahul: Then the final clause of my answer is 100% correct. What a ridiculous and useless thing to ask in an interview. To the interviewer I would have stated "don't be so stupid" and if I didn't get the job for that analysis, I would be glad!

Comment: @sehe, context is important, but to dismiss something as being "silly" without the context is plain silly IMHO. @Tomalak, of course not, the point I'm making is that the mere existence implies that there were/is some situation where it was/is pertinent, and to make a general statement dismissing an approach is "silly".

Comment: @Rahul Dravid, the answer implies an array of these structures, which seems perfectly valid to me. If they wanted an array of `void*` pointers, I would agree with Tomalak, that's just plain stupid.

Comment: if the answer  implies an array of these structure..then how could somebody retrieve an object from an element in that array?

Comment: @Nim: can you post an authoritative source on when it is ok to label something 'plain silly' as opposed to 'silly'? I'm missing the subtle distinction :)

Comment: @Rahul: How do you retrieve any object from any array?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: you can view entire program memory as a big array of bytes holding lots of objects of different unrelated types, that said every program is silly.

Comment: @Konstantin: If you were looking at the very lowest level, sure. We're not.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: yeah, who'd need low level in the C++? Anyhow, I didn't see any level mentioned in the original question and in your answer as well. And, by the way, did you imply that there are contexts where it's not silly?

Comment: @Konstantin: Lowest level means bytes of machine code. The level we're talking about is the layer where C++ resides: an abstraction layer between machine code and higher-level logic.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: that's the same level I'm talking about. When you allocate memory in C or C++, all you get is an array of bytes which then could be interpreted as an object of some type, an array of objects or an 'array' of objects of different types. Lots of memory allocators working upon C++ abstraction level do this silly thing.

Comment: "Object" is well-defined in C++. I no longer have any clue what you're talking about.

Comment: Did I ever said it's not well defined?

Comment: Implementing a memory allocator which reserves a chunk of memory and then creates objects of different types there is perfectly valid and reasonable thing to do. As a result you'll have an array storing objects of different classes.

Comment: @Konstantin: If you're writing a memory allocator, you're wilfully throwing away some of the abstraction that the language provides (and expects you to use). Usually, you're not.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: It's possible to do this in 100% standard compliant C++. If you think it's not could you please be more specific about abstractions we have to abandon?

Comment: @Konstantin: Just because you don't have to violate the standard to do something, is not carte blanche to go ahead and do it.

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't see how it's related to our discussion. If doing something doesn't violate standard, it means that it is done within abstraction provided by the language. Also, implementing memory allocator doesn't require you to obscure brain-damaging code.

Comment: @Tomalak: yep, I didn't expected any reasonable arguments proving it's really a silly thing to do.

Comment: @Konstantin: Have a read through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_silence and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance

Comment: @Tomalak: thanks for interesting reading. Although, I never told you are wrong because you can't/don't want to prove your proposition. I'm telling you are wrong because, I have, in my opinion, adduced a reasonable counter-example.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `boost::variant<myfoo, anotherfoo, somefoo> v` to put into a `vector<v>` and then you can store one class per item in the vector, however it can store variables of all three types.

You can find more info on boost::variant [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: he was expecting an answer  not using any library like boost.

Comment: @Rahul, oh ok... didn't know. But this could work however, IRL

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic_cast` from `void*` is not allowed, you need a polymorphic pointer for that (that is, a pointer to a class with a `virtual` method in it).

You cannot use other casts because the target type of the cast is not known. Once you cast a typed pointer to `void*`, the type information is lost forever. Given just the pointer, you have no chance to get that type information back. You need to remember something about the type somewhere in some form. How about `enum { one, two, three }` alongside the `void*` ?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` would be fine.

Comment: @Tomalak `reinterpret_cast<???>` What do you write inside the brackets? There are three types to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

The only "correct" way to do this is to use something like
`boost::variant`.  If you cannot use boost, then you have to more less
do the same thing: implement a discriminate union which accepts all of
the desired types.  This isn't as hard as it might seem: for POD types,
you can just use a normal `union` for the data; for non-POD types, you
add a `unsigned char x[sizeof(T)]` to the union, and use placement new and
explicit delete on it, as needed.  And you add whatever is necessary to
the union to ensure alignment.  Thus, for a user type MyClass and a double,
one might have something like:

```
class MyVariant
{
public:
    enum Type { t_double, t_MyClass };
private:
    Type m_type;
    union
    {
        double m_double;
        unsigned char m_MyClass[sizeof(MyClass)];
        MaxAlignFor<MyClass> m_dummyForAlignment_MyClass;
    };
public:
    MyVariant( double d )
        : m_type( t_double )
    {
        m_double = d;
    }
    MyVariant( MyClass const& c )
        : m_type( t_MyClass )
    {
        new (m_MyClass) MyClass( c );
    }
    ~MyVariant()
    {
        switch ( m_type )
        {
        case t_double:
            break;

        case t_MyClass:
            reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>( m_MyClass )->~MyClass();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

And so on.  (There's obviously a lot more involved, but this should give
the basic framework.)